# Are there ways to find representations of matrices given an algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given an equation (or a set of equations) involving matrices, is there an algorithm to find possible representations of these matrices?

For example, we can consider a matrix $A$ such that
$A^2=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$. Now one possible representation could be $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, another could be $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$.

As another example, we can consider an algebra involving two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $AB=A + B$. Now is it possible to find possible representations of $A$ and $B$? For this particular case, it is known that no finite dimensional representations exist.

But we could consider more general cases involving a larger number of matrices and more equations that they have to satisfy. In that case, are there any general algorithms to find possible representations?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What is a representation of a matrix? Do you mean something like representations of $\Bbb C[x]$, where $x$ acts on some module via $A$?

Comment: By a representation I meant finding the elements of a matrix $a_{ij}$ which would satisfy the given algebra. I have edited the question a bit for more clarity.